# Can my color function be written more simply?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, graphics3d, color

The code shown below works well, but I think the pure function I'm supplying to the ColorFunction option could be more elegant. How can I simplify it?

```
f3[w_, h_, z_, d_: 0.04] := 
  Reap[Do[If[Abs[i]/w + Abs[j]/h + Abs[k]/z == 1, 
      Sow@{i, j, k}], {i, -w, w, d}, {j, -h, h, d}, {k, -z, z, 
      d}]][[2, 1]];

ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02,
 ColorFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] Which[
     z > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, Red,
     z > 0 && x > 0 && y < 0, Green,
     z > 0 && x < 0 && y > 0, Blue,
     z > 0 && x < 0 && y < 0, Orange,

     z < 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, Cyan,
     z < 0 && x > 0 && y < 0, Magenta,
     z < 0 && x < 0 && y > 0, Yellow,
     z < 0 && x < 0 && y < 0, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1],
     True, Black]), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow,  RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1], Black};
 clrRls = Sequence @@ Join @@ Thread[{Append[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], _],  colors}]; 
 ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z}, Switch[Sign[{z, x, y}], ##] &@clrRls])]
```

or

```
clrRls2 = Flatten@Thread[{Append[And @@@ Tuples[{Greater[#, 0], Less[#, 0]} & /@
  {z, x, y}], True], colors}];
ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02,  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z}, ##] &[Which @@ clrRls2])]
```

[image]

**Update:** Further alternatives:

Cycling through the colors based on the sign patterns of the coordinates:

```
  positionRls = Thread[Append[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], {_, _, _}] -> Range[9]]; 
  ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1],  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[.02],
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
     With[{pos = Sign[{z, x, y}] /. positionRls}, colors[[pos]]]]]
```

Using `PlotStyle` instead of `ColorFunction`:

```
 dispatch = Thread[Append[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], {_, _, _}] -> colors]; 
 ListPointPlot3D[{#} & /@ f3[1, 1, 1], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thread[{PointSize[.02], (Sign[RotateRight@#] & /@ f3[1, 1, 1] /. 
  dispatch)}]]
```

Specifying point colors during `Sow`ing and use with `PlotStyle`:

```
  f4[w_, h_, z_, d_: 0.04] :=  Reap[Do[If[Abs[i]/w + Abs[j]/h + Abs[k]/z == 1, 
     Sow[{{{i, j, k}}, Sign[{k, i, j}] /. dispatch}]], 
     {i, -w, w, d}, {j, -h, h, d}, {k, -z, z, d}]][[2, 1]];
  ListPointPlot3D[f4[1, 1, 1][[All, 1]], 
   PlotStyle -> (Directive[{PointSize[.02], #}] & /@ f4[1, 1, 1][[All, 2]]),
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

or, with `Graphics3D` instead of `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
  f5[w_, h_, z_, d_: 0.04] :=   Reap[Do[If[Abs[i]/w + Abs[j]/h + Abs[k]/z == 1, 
  Sow[{Sign[{k, i, j}] /. dispatch, Point@{i, j, k}}]], 
   {i, -w, w,   d}, {j, -h, h, d}, {k, -z, z, d}]][[2, 1]];
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], f5[1, 1, 1]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possible way of rewriting it:

```
cf = Block[{x, y, z},
    Which @@ Flatten[{
        Thread[{
            And[x ~#~ 0, y ~#2~ 0, z ~#3~ 0] & @@@ Tuples[{Greater, Less}, 3], 
            {Red, Cyan, Green, Magenta, Blue, Yellow, Orange, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1]}
        }], 
        True, Black
    }]
]

ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] Evaluate@cf)]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think I have the colors around the wrong way, the `Black` catch-all doesn't get used - but this is as simple as I can get it.

```
colors = Reverse@{Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, 
        Magenta, Yellow,  RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1], Black}

 ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02, 
 ColorFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] 
    colors[[ FromDigits[UnitStep /@ {z, x, y}, 2] +1]]), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I enjoy your solution. BTW, the minor error in your code can be fixed in this way: ColorFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] 
    colors[[ FromDigits[UnitStep /@ {z, x, y}, 2]+1 ]], since there is no colors[[0]] at all.

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of kguler's code, mine comes as:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, 
   RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1]};

clrRls = Sequence @@ 
  Riffle[Distribute[ConstantArray[{-1, 1}, 3], List], colors]
ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Switch[Sign[{z, x, y}], ##] &@clrRls])]
```

Answer (score 4):

A way under spherical coordinates system:

```
colorSwitchFunc = Function[expr, Evaluate@Module[
    {colorset = {Red, Blue, Orange, Green, Cyan, Yellow, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1], Magenta}},
    Switch[expr, ##] & @@ Flatten[Prepend[
       {Tuples @ Range @ {2, 4}, colorset}\[Transpose],
       {{0, _} | {_, 0}, Black}], 1]
    ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
   Module[{θ = ArcCos[z/2(*Norm[{x,y,z}]*)], ϕ = If[# < 0, 2 π + #, #] &@Arg[x + y I]},
    {θ, ϕ}/(π/2) /. n_?(FractionalPart[#] == 0 &) :> 0 // Ceiling // colorSwitchFunc ]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note in `θ = ArcCos[z/2(*Norm[{x,y,z}]*)]`, for better speed, the real `Norm` is replaced by a constant (here $2$) larger than the maximum absolute value of `z`.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of fun different suggestions, Didn't see this one pressented so here goes:

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1]};

cf[x_, y_, z_] := 
   Switch[Sign[{x, y, z}], 
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Riffle[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], colors]], _, Black];

ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1], PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02, 
ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

I think there's enough pictures of the results already.

---

Here is a modification that maintains the ability to change colors conveniently yet speeds the application of the function by partial pre-evaluation.

```
cfGen[colors_] :=
  Riffle[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], colors] /.
    _[seq__] :> (Switch[Sign @ {##}, seq, _, Black] &)
```

Usage is: `ColorFunction -> cfGen[colors]`.

Alternatively:

```
Block[{colors, Part},
 cf =
   Riffle[Tuples[{1, -1}, 3], colors[[#]] & ~Array~ 8] /.
    _[seq__] :> (Switch[Sign @ {##}, seq, _, Black] &)
];
```

`cf` then has the definition:

```
Switch[Sign[{##1}],
  {1, 1, 1},   colors[[1]],
  {1, 1, -1},  colors[[2]],
  {1, -1, 1},  colors[[3]],
  {1, -1, -1}, colors[[4]],
  {-1, 1, 1},  colors[[5]],
  {-1, 1, -1}, colors[[6]],
  {-1, -1, 1}, colors[[7]],
  {-1, -1, -1},colors[[8]],
  _, Black] &
```

Comment: +1 for the correction.  It might be a bit faster to inject that sequence directly into the definition so that it is not reevaluated every time the function is called.  Edit: Yes, that is about three times as fast.  May I make the change?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, you could do that, but strictly speaking it wouldn't be the same, since the current implementation allows you to change the colors at any point while the faster version would have you redefine the function to change colors. For a fun illustration of the difference, try using `ColorFunction -> ((colors = RotateRight@colors; cf[##]) &)`. :)

Comment: I've got a solution to that.  I can add it to your answer, or mine.  Your choice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Feel free to add it here if you'd like.

Comment: Edit made.  It ended up longer than I intended but I hope you don't mind.  (And if you do, just revert the change.)

Answer (score 3):

My take on kguler's first method.  First a refactoring of the `f3` code:

```
f3[w_, h_, z_, d_: 0.04] :=
  Select[
    Tuples @ Range[-{w, h, z}, {w, h, z}, d],
    Dot[Abs@#, 1/{w, h, z}] == 1 &
  ]
```

#### Rules

```
colors = {Red, Cyan, Green, Magenta, Blue, Yellow, Orange, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1], Black};

clrRls = Thread[Append[{1, -1} ~Tuples~ 3, _] -> colors];

ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Sign@{##} /. clrRls &)
]
```

#### Definitions

Alternatively:

```
colors = {Red, Cyan, Green, Magenta, Blue, Yellow, Orange, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1]};

fn[x_, y_, z_] := fn @ Sign @ {x, y, z}

MapThread[(fn[#] = #2) &, {{1, -1} ~Tuples~ 3, colors}];

fn[other_] = Black;

ListPointPlot3D[f3[1, 1, 1],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize@0.02,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> fn
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]